# SQL Server Combine Duplicate Entries

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a Microsoft SQL table with the following data:

```
CustomerID   Location1   Location2
788          A           NULL
788          A           B
788          B           NULL
649          A           NULL
649          NULL        B
936          B           NULL
```

I'd like to be able to query this table and return just the CustomerID and the combined unique locations.

```
CustomerID   Location1   Location2
788          A           B
649          A           B
936          B
```

```
Select Distinct CustomerID, MAX(Location1) L1, MAX(Location2) L2
FROM table
GROUP BY CustomerID
```

returns

```
CustomerID   L1   L2
788          B    B
649          B
936          B
```

Having a difficult time working this one out.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you could coalesce your thoughts a bit and share what you have tried so far and what went wrong.

Comment: Select Distinct CustomerID, COALESCE(Location1, Location2)

Sort of works but I end up with
788    A
788   B
649   A
649   B
936   B

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan what's the solution with `coalesce`??

Comment: Thats not really working either. Im getting
788   B   B

Comment: @JamesBrown if there is (111, 11, null) and (111, 12, null), which one should be picked?

Comment: @Zakaria Id like it to be 111, 11, 12

Comment: @JamesBrown definitely add it as an example!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should solve OP's last comments:

```
with u as
(select CustomerID, Location1 as L
from Table1
where Location1 is not null
union select CustomerID, Location2 as L 
from Table1
where Location2 is not null)
(select customerID, min(L) as Location1, case when max(L) <> min(L) then max(L) end as Location2
from u
group by CustomerID)
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d8b0f9c8a8b3c7b3133b10d9ec55035e)

Or using the same trick from the other answer:

```
Select CustomerID
       , MIN(coalesce(Location1,Location2)) L1
       , case when MAX(coalesce(Location2,Location1)) <> MIN(coalesce(Location1,Location2)) then MAX(coalesce(Location1,Location2)) end L2
FROM table
GROUP BY CustomerID
```

Answer (score 1):

use min and max:

```
Select CustomerID
       , MIN(coalesce(Location1,Location2)) L1
       , MAX(coalesce(Location2,Location1)) L2
FROM table
GROUP BY CustomerID
```

Comment: Thanks @eshirvana!  That almost works.  I have some Values like
CustomerID   Location1   Location2
   1674              A                NULL
   1674              B                NULL

Comment: @JamesBrown how about this , see updated answer ,

Comment: I can work with that.  Thank you!